# $T:X\to Z$, $S:Y\to Z$ be given linear maps and $X,Y,Z$ be given Banach spaces, if $\forall x\in X$, $Tx=Sy$ has unique solution y.

Tags: functional-analysis

$T:X\to Z$, $S:Y\to Z$ be given linear maps and  $X,Y,Z$ be given Banach spaces, if $\forall x\in X$, $Tx=Sy$ has unique solution y. Then $M:X\to Y$, $Mx=y$ is continuous.

The intuition says that  $M=S^{-1}T$ because for every $x\in X$ I can find unique $y$

such that $Tx=Sy$.

I first try to show $S$ is invertible and then $S^{-1}T$ is bijective then since $S^{-1}T:X\to Y$ then it is isometry so it is continuous. However I'm lost at showing it.

Secondly I try to use Closed  Graph Theorem but again without showing the invertibility of $S$ I cannot go further.

I am open for every suggestion and solutions, hints.

Comment: I think you are missing some crucial hypothesis. Don't have continuity of $S$ and $T$?

Comment: $T,S$ are given as $T\in L(X,Z)$ and  $S\in L(Y,Z)$, I think $L $ means linear space not bounded linear space

Comment: No. $L(X,Y)$ is the space of  continuous linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ in standard notations.

Comment: Thank, you , I always think $B(X,Y)$ is the bounded linear space because I read a lot in Kreyszig but this notation then was diffrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming continuity of $S$ and $T$ this follows easily by Closed Graph Theorem: Let $x_n \to x, y_n \to z$ with $y_n=Mx_n$. Then $Tx_n=Sy_n$. Hence $Sz=\lim Sy_n =\lim Tx_n=Tx$. By definition this gives $z=Mx$. Hence $M$ has closed graph.